# how do I make searching/pagination reusable in my application?

Tags: c#, javascript, angularjs, pagination

We decided to use server-side pagination in our application. The implementation is quite simple:

- suppose we have such a search action on the server side:

  ```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult GetPeopleByName(String term, Int32 itemsPerPage = 10, Int32 page = 0) {
      var matches = this.people.Where(i => i.Name.Contains(term));
      return Json(
          data: new {
              people = matches.Skip(itemsPerPage * page).Take(itemsPerPage).OrderBy(i => i.Name),
              total = matches.Count()
          },
          behavior: JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
      );
  }
  ```
- on the client we have a `subscriptionHolderController`:

  ```
  app.controller('subscriptionHolderController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.matches = [];
      $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
      $scope.currentPage = 0;
      $scope.searchTerm = '';

      // $scope.prevPage = function() { ... };
      // $scope.prevPageDisabled = function() { ... };
      // $scope.nextPage = function() { ... };
      // $scope.nextPageDisabled = function() { ... };

      $scope.pageCount = function() { 
          return Math.ceil($scope.totalPages / $scope.itemsPerPage); 
      };

      $scope.$watch('currentPage', function() { $scope.search(); });

      $scope.search = function() {
          if($scope.searchTerm === '') return;
          // initiate a GET-request with params: { page: $scope.currentPage, term: $scope.searchTerm, itemsPerPage: $scope.itemsPerPage }
      }
      $scope.matchesFound = function () { return $scope.matches.length > 0; }
  }]);
  ```

**problem**

As the result we have a simple `search-box`. But our application requires one more type of search with some additional features, it doesn't use search terms and its resulting set *should be paginated the same way as it is shown above*.

How do I reuse pagination logic for a different types of search?

Comment: One idea would be to separate the paging logic + UI as a directive with isolated scope. That would enable you to use it in multiple places. Take a look at the directive section[https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive] in angular documentation.

Comment: are you interested in re-using the client or server side?

Comment: @DaveA I want to fetch data from server by portions/pages whether it is an input (on the client side) and you're sending a `search term`, `page info` or it is a `set of parameters` bound to say `radioboxes` and you're sending `page info` + `that parameters`

Comment: @CMR could you please illustrate how do I make such a directive?

Comment: One quick solution would be to use something like this > http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination . You provide the parameters from your controller and you are done. If this doesn't work for you, you have to opt for a custom pager directive. Let me know if that is the route you want to go and we can discuss further and perhaps build a jsFiddle as a sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the server side you can return a generic class for which is going to hold your data, the total of rows.

```
public class PagedResult<T>
    {
        public PagedResult(IEnumerable<T> data, long total)
        {
            Data = data;
            Total = total;
        }
        public PagedResult()
        {
        }
        public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }
        public long Total { get; set; }

    }
```

and also you can abstract the input parameters for any function something like:

```
public class PageInfo
    {

        public int Page { get; set; }           
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public int Skip
        {
            get
            {
                return PageSize*(Page - 1);
            }
        }

        public PageInfo(int page, int pageSize)
        {
            Page = page;
            PageSize = pageSize;
        }

    }
```

and a practical example could be something like:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetPeopleByName(String term, PageInfo pageinfo) {
    var matches = this.people.Where(i => i.Name.Contains(term));

    var pagedResult =  new PagedResult<AnySearchType>{
            data = matches.Skip(pageinfo.skip).Take(pageinfo.size).OrderBy(i => i.Name),
            total = matches.Count()
        };

    return Json(
        data: pagedResult,
        behavior: JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    );
}
```

on the client side you can use a directive to abstract the logic for the paging by passing parameters like:

**view**

```
<div class="box-content" scroll-pager="pagerConfig">
your data
<div>
```

**controller:**

you can pass some configuration like:

```
$scope.pagerConfig = {
        pageSize: 10,
        data: 'model.Data', // some text reference to your model
        total: 'model.Total', // some text reference to your model
        currentPage: 1,
        searchParamName: 'Text',// some text reference to your model
        resource: projectResource,// pass a resource object
        success: function (data, page, total) {

            }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Make separate class for paging. In this class you can define methods for paging you can apply paging to any type and with different parameters also you can customize the fields on which to apply paging and page size.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with:

```
app.directive('pager', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            onChange: '&',
            items: '=',
            itemsPerPage: '@'
        },
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/scripts/js/app/pager.html',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.currentPage = 1;

            scope.isFirstPage = function() {
                return scope.currentPage === 1;
            }

            scope.decPage = function() {
                if(scope.currentPage > 1) --scope.currentPage;
            }

            scope.isLastPage = function() {
                return scope.currentPage >= scope.totalPages();
            }

            scope.totalPages = function() {
                return Math.ceil(scope.items.total / scope.itemsPerPage);
            }

            scope.incPage = function() {
                if(!scope.isLastPage()) ++scope.currentPage;
            }

            scope.$watch("currentPage", function(value) {
                scope.onChange({page: value, itemsPerPage: scope.itemsPerPage});
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**markup**

```
<div id="content" ng-app="subscriptionsManager">
    <div ng-controller="subscriptionHolderController">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="columns medium-6 large-6">
                <div class="searchbar">
                    <div class="searchbar-inner">
                        <input ng-model="searchTerm" type="text" />
                        <button ng-click="search(1, 35)" class="tiny">search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div pager items-per-page="35" items="data" on-change="respondToTheChange(page, itemsPerPage)"></div>
           </div>
           <div class="columns medium-6 large-6">
                <div class="button-group filter-sample">
                     <button ng-click="toggleState1()" ng-class="{true: 'selected', false: 'secondary'}[state1]" class="tiny">filter1</button>
                     <button ng-click="toggleState2()" ng-class="{true: 'selected', false: 'secondary'}[state2]" class="tiny">filter2</button>
                     <button ng-click="toggleState3()" ng-class="{true: 'selected', false: 'secondary'}[state3]" class="tiny">filter3</button>
                     <button ng-click="search2(1, 35)" class="tiny">search</button>
                </div>
                <div pager items-per-page="35" items="data2" on-change="respondToTheChange2(page, itemsPerPage)"></div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
// search using a search term

$scope.data = { items: [], total: 0 };
$scope.searchTerm = '';

$scope.state1 = false;
$scope.state2 = false;
$scope.state3 = false;

$scope.toggleState1 = function() {
    $scope.state1 = !$scope.state1;
}

$scope.toggleState2 = function() {
    $scope.state2 = !$scope.state2;
}

$scope.toggleState3 = function() {
    $scope.state3 = !$scope.state3;
}

$scope.search = function(page, itemsPerPage) {
    if($scope.searchTerm === '') return;
    if(!angular.isDefined(page) || page == null) page = 1;
    if(!angular.isDefined(itemsPerPage) || itemsPerPage == null) itemsPerPage = 35;

    $http({
        url: '/subscriptions/GetSubscribersByNamePaged',
        method: 'GET',
        params: { term: $scope.searchTerm, page: page, itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage }
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error: ' + data);
    });
}

// search using anything else

$scope.search2 = function(page, itemsPerPage) {
    if(!angular.isDefined(page) || page == null) page = 1;
    if(!angular.isDefined(itemsPerPage) || itemsPerPage == null) itemsPerPage = 35;

    $http({
        url: '/subscriptions/GetSubscribersByFilters',
        method: 'GET',
        params: { state1: $scope.state1, state2: $scope.state2, state3: $scope.state3, page: page, itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage }
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data2 = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error: ' + data);
    });
}

// bind searches!

$scope.respondToTheChange = function(page, itemsPerPage) {
    $scope.search(page, itemsPerPage);
}

$scope.respondToTheChange2 = function(page, itemsPerPage) {
    $scope.search2(page, itemsPerPage);
}
```